# Starting with an empty tree, what is the complexity of inserting into Red Black Tree in big-O notation?

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, red-black-tree

If I have 10 elements and starting with an empty tree, What is the complexity of inserting 10 elements into Red Black in big-O notation?

Is it going to be more than O(log 10) because each time it inserts an element, it has to search for appropriate location for the element and performs a series of rotations between ancestor nodes and child nodes. So if I have N element and inserting N times into Red Black Tree, wouldn't that make it O(n log n)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10):

You never use big-O with a constant (except 1) because O(10) means exactly the same as O(1) or O(128291), so by convention you always use O(1)!

So, let's see what's the big-O of inserting K items into an initially empty RB-tree.  The first insertion is a constant time so call it O(1); and inserting when there are X items the X+1st is O(log(X)) (even if you have to rotate each step down, it's still worst-case proportional to log(X), so, O(log(X)), because the number of "layers", or "levels", only grows logarithmically with X -- since an RB tree for K levels has a number of nodes that grows as 2 to the Kth power).

So we want the summation of log(X) for X from 2 to N (plus a costant), which happens to be equal to the log of the factorial of N.  Per [Stirling's approx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), that's about N log(N) - N, which in big-O terms boils down to N log(N) again.

Comment: @John, so if you like it why not accept it (use the checkmark under the big "number of upvotes" digit at the top left of the question) -- that's fundamental SO etiquette and would get you started on the SO reputation ladder (yes, you gain rep by accepting!-).

Comment: @AlexMartelli I believe you have a small typo: inserting when there are X items is `O(logX)` instead of `O(X)`. Nice answer btw, +1.

Comment: @MiljenMikic, you're right -- editing to fix & congrats for being first to spot this in more than 5 years!-)

Answer (score 2):

What @Justice and @Alex are really getting at is that a `O(f(N))` complexity measure talks about the limiting behavior (e.g. time to run, number of comparisons, whatever) as N tends to infinity.

They are saying that if you substitute a particular value for N, the `O` terminology is no longer meaningful.

There is another point that they didn't make.  That is that you cannot use a statement in `O(...)` notation to tell you what happens when N is small.  By definition "big O" notation tells you nothing about what happens in that case.

This is not just pedantry.  For example the cost function `F(N) = 1,000,000 * N + N**2` is `O(N**2)`, but the first term dominates for values of N less than 1,000.  If you try to use the `O(N**2)` measure as an estimator in this case, you will get totally the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

The time-complexity of inserting a single element into an RB-tree is `O(log n)` where `n` is the current size of the tree.

The time-complexity of inserting `n` elements into an empty RB-tree is, therefore, `O(n log n)`.

The time-complexity of inserting `10` elements into an empty RB-tree is constant, or `O(1)`. Because the tree starts empty, and because the number of elements being inserted is fixed, there are no variable elements here.